# access denied when I try to upload file on express

Tags: express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I got error something like this

**[google-id].gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to upload**

I already make my bucket as public, and the service account as owner, or I did something missing for set it up ??? 
I was trying to upload files on my express , to test it , I am new for this, 
can anyone tell me what's wrong and what I should set ???

Answer (score 3):

One way to give permissions to your application/user would be through the following command:

```
gsutil iam ch user:[google-id].gserviceaccount.com:objectCreator gs://[YOUR_BUCKET]
```

This is fully documented at [Using Cloud IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions).  You can also perform this action using Cloud Console.  An example of using that interface is provided in the documentation previously linked.